# Populating input field with JSON data

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've received a JSON object from my server and I want it to loop through all the returned values and populate two input text fields, which are created dynamically.

At the moment I have 2 records returned but it only populates one set of fields and the other set although created remains unpopulated. The `console.log` output shows there are two records:

```
0 Object {emailAdd: "bob@work.com", emailDesc: "work"} 
1 Object {emailAdd: "john@home.com", emailDesc: "home"}
```

This is the Jquery:

```
var emails = {% raw json_encode(emails) %};
$.each(emails, function(k,v) {
    x = 1;
    z = x++;
    $('<input type="email" placeholder="Email" value="" id="email'+x+'" data-name="emailAdd" /><input type="text" placeholder="Description" value="" id="email'+z+'" data-name="emailDesc"/>').appendTo('#email');
    $('#email' + x + '').val(v.emailAdd);
    $('#email' + z + '').val(v.emailDesc);
    x++;
    console.log(k, v); 
});
```

It seems to be just returning the last record, instead of all records. How can I show all the returned records?

Comment: You don't have any JSON there. The context you are using it in means the output of your server side template language is a JavaScript object literal.

Comment: Don't know if this is causing the issue but you are setting the id of the div always just to "email"... id's need to be unique...

Comment: @nothing9, he is appending "x" and "z" in "email string", so I think this is not the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are initializing var `x` on every `each` iteration. You could try this:

```
var emails = {% raw json_encode(emails) %};
x=1;
$.each(emails, function(k,v) {
z=x++;
$('<div class="form-group1" name ="email" id="email"><input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" value="" id="email'+x+'" data-name="emailAdd" /><br><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Description" value="" id="email'+z+'" data-name="emailDesc"/></div>').appendTo('#email');
$('#email'+x+'').val(v.emailAdd);
$('#email'+z+'').val(v.emailDesc);
x++;
console.log(k,v); 
});
```

Demo fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/orooct3q/

Comment: @Ipg Thanks for the spot. I was reinitializing the value back to one.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
emails = JSON.parse('{% raw json_encode(emails) %}'); // or use $.parseJSON()

$.each(emails, function(k,v) {
    // code goes here
    console.log(k,v); 
});
```

Comment: There's no need to call `JSON.parse`. JSON can be used as a Javascript literal.

Answer (score 1):

Your code overwrites the previous values since you start counting `x=1` in each loop. The following should show you all the data:

```
var emails = {% raw json_encode(emails) %};
$.each(emails, function(k,v) {
    $('<div class="form-group1" name ="email" id="email"><input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" value="" id="email' + k + '-0" data-name="emailAdd" /><br><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Description" value="" id="email' + z + '-1" data-name="emailDesc"/></div>').appendTo('#email');
    $('#email'+k+'-0').val(v.emailAdd);
    $('#email'+k+'-1').val(v.emailDesc);
    console.log(k,v); 
});
```